# About .length property for int

Tags: java

So i am studying on a code used to convert scores to grade, I am a bit confused with the following steps:

```
public static String score2grade(int score){
  int [] bottoms = {95, 90, 85, 80};
  String [] grade = {A+, A, A-, B+};
  for(int i = 1; i < bottoms.length; i++){
     if (score >= bottoms[i]) return grade[i];
```

I don't really understand the `int i = 1; i < bottoms.length; i++` part, so what is i here basically? and what is the length property of `bottoms` ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: `i` in that loop starts out at 1 and increments until it reaches the value that is one below `bottoms.length`, which in this case is 4. (notice how this means that it won't access `bottoms[0]`)

Comment: Any introductory Java tutorial is going to cover the concept of `for` loops.  You might want to start there.

Comment: .length is used with int array. ".length" is used to tell the no of elements in integer array. And, i<bottoms.length means loop should run upto  length-1

Comment: i is just an  increment  variable used in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In Java the length property means the maximum number of elements you're using in the array bottoms[]. Here the length of bottoms[] array is 3. Since at '0' place the element 95 exists. At '1' place the element 90 exists. And at '2' place the element 85 exists. And at '3' place element 80 exists.

The part of code is used for iteration . Basically it says start counting from one . And in first loop increment the value of i by 1. And keep doing this procedure until the value of i is less than the length of the bottoms array. And when its equal the loop just breaks .